# How to Increase or Decrease Volume in Decimals in Android

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I am making a simple app with inc and dec buttons. I want to increase or decrease the volume very slowly.

Code snippet:

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

In audio.adjustStreamVolume can the increment value be in fractions, so that the volume can be more precise tested?

Comment: the parameter type is `int`, which means `no floating point numbers`. So the answer is no (no easy way). As for me it is quite enough to have 100 possible volume positions. I can't imagine option where you will need more than that. I bet that if you even could use decimal volume, you didn't hear the difference between `1` and `1.5`

Comment: the volume goes from 1 to 15. if it had been 1 to 50 then i am ok with int,because there are more places. If the sound cant be figured out between 1 and 1.5 then it will not be ncessary. but how can  i test that in android

Comment: ok, that's right. I've mixed things with the MediaPlayer volume. As for `AudioManager` - it is something like system limitation that you can set the volume only corresponding to system defined steps. I think that you should explain why you need to change the `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` volume, and maybe we awould be able to offer better solution.

Comment: I have a certain limit for volume in my place. I am perfectly fine if there will not be not much difference between 1 unit change. Because i am connecting my device to a speaker again.

Comment: I'm afraid that there will be significant difference if there are only 15 positions. I said that there is no difference thinking that there are 100 positions.

Comment: Today i checked the audio. My android phone is connected to a bluetooth speaker. I increased 1 unit and i found there is a significant increase in the volume. I need more smoother way to transit

Comment: I think there is no such way (without root at least)

Comment: how to do it with root

Comment: with root, you can at least increase number of steps. This differs for each device, so you will have to find for your device

Comment: i have a rooted phone how to change the number of steps. In which file i have to change

Comment: I had to search in google for ~14 seconds to find and answer. You should definitely try too.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46979/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-volume-levels (is this you mean)

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?safe=off&ei=SLK3Wr2hMJClwQLmwbmoDw&q=android+volume+steps+number+root&oq=android+volume+steps+number+root&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.763.763.0.987.1.1.0.0.0.0.109.109.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.109....0.YWj8RauZdzU

Comment: Thank you, The main purpose to know the solution is so that i want to create my own app

Comment: it makes no sense to do that because too small number of users have root access, and even less of them will let your app get that access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to increase the number of volume steps.

I found the answer here:
https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-add-more-steps-to-your-volume-slider-root/

Basically i have to add:

ro.config.media_vol_steps=60 (since i want 60 steps of volume control)

to the file build.prop file located in /system

This can be edited using buildedit pro. but it needs root access. How to do that i have explained late below.

Then reboot the system then we can see my android app with the same code in my question uses 60 increment steps than 15

Since to edit this build.prop file one needs root access. So i have to install kingroot.

the procedure to install kingroot is given at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuECdDIJmXQ